# SQL impala generate Standard deviation manually

Tags: sql, impala, expand, standard-deviation

I have a table like this:

| values | frequencies | grpng |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | cat1 |
| 3 | 2 | cat1 |
| 4 | 1 | cat1 |
| 2 | 2 | cat2 |
| 1 | 1 | cat2 |
| 5 | 2 | cat2 |

I want to generate the standard deviation (population sd) per group (cat1, cat2)
not with a window function but by grouping wrt to the grpng variable.
I see two options:

1. Expand the values using the frequencies and then use the standard sql sd dev function.
2. Directly group and get the sd dev manually if possible.

Can you suggest a solution? For the first option I am not able to find a function to expand in Impala.

My desired outcome is:

| sddev | grpng |
| --- | --- |
| 0.70710678118655 | cat1 |
| 1.6733200530682 | cat2 |